# Is it common to have a pressure shut off for Jet Water Pumps?

Tags: pump, well-pump

I'm looking at installing a pump for a domestic water supply with a pressure tank.  I'd like to be able to determine if a pump will shut off once it has reached pressure.

I've seen several pumps installed which seem to shut off automatically but I can't seem to figure out if this is a standard feature or not because it doesn't seem to appear in their specifications.  For example, this grundfos pump is commonly used and I've seen other grundfos's shut off automatically at pressure.  Is this standard for a jet water pump?
[image: grundfos]
http://www.supplyhouse.com/Grundfos-97855088-JP4-61ASI-Shallow-Well-Basic-Line-Stainless-Steel-Jet-Pump-115-230V-1-HP

I am asking because I'd like to try a different brand but I can not tell if it has a built in shut off:
[image: pump]

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00NAKPSRC?ref_=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NAKPSRC)
I've contacted the manufacturer, but with little response.  Is anyone familiar with jet pumps like this and what I should look for to fit this application?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

After some time the manufacturer indicated that there is a port on the side for the pressure switch and sent a photo of one installed.  So now I know that's probably the standard way most jet pumps come so they can be externally configured to different PSI settings.

[image: with switch]

Comment: Do be aware that often times you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a standard feature. The pump often hooks into a manifold that connects to the pressure tank and that has a check-valve, pressure gauge, pressure switch, tank drain valve, main shutoff valve, and over-pressure relief valve. The assembly looks like the following once assembled (note: check-valve not shown in this setup).

[image]

You will have to consult the manufacturer's spec sheets to see if it comes with an integral pressure switch. Even if the manufacturer won't respond, often they have spec sheets and manuals available online that will give you this info.

Note: the bottom pump is a no-brand Chinese manufacture pump, you might be able to trace it through Ali-Baba, but you'll have to take the Amazon description's word for what it does as there's not much else available about it online.

Comment: I've seen these pressure switches too.  However several of these jet pumps I've seen in action (other brands) seem to not have one externally mounted.  They have a boxy thing on top of the motor like the ones shown in my question.  Neither manufacturer seems to have any data indicating an internal pressure switches though.  It does look like the grundfos (the first pump shown) has a pressure switch installed externally to the right near the motor.

Comment: The boxy thing probably has a start capacitor and possibly jumpers for switching between running 120 and 240V inside it. It is an electrical enclosure and therefore will not have a pressure switch inside it as a leaking diaphragm would seep water directly into the motor housing.

Comment: You're right.  That's the housing for the power.